# How can I change position of dropdown block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have dropdown form. It appears on button hover. I tried to make it drop to the top when it drops down to the invisible part of the window, but my function doesn't work

HTML:

```
<div class="main-btn">
  <p><a href="#">Free call</a>
  <br/>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
  <form class="popover-form">
    <label for="">Name</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label for="">Phonenum</label>
    <input type="text" value="+375">
    <button>Call me!</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-btn .popover-form {
  display: none;
}

.main-btn {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
}

.main-btn:hover .popover-form {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 87px;
  left: 0;
  background: #edeae4;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 285px;
}
```

JS:

```
function changePosition() {
    var currentForm = $(this).find('.popover-form');

    if ((this.offset().top + currentForm.height()) > $(window).height()) {
      currentForm.css('bottom', '87px');
      currentForm.css('right', '0');
    }
}

$('.main-btn').on('onmouseover', changePosition);
```

Comment: `this.offset().top` needs to be `$(this).offset().top`

Comment: (`'onmouseover'`) needs to be just (`'mouseover'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code. change `bottom , 87px` to `top , $(this).offset().top` in css function

```
  function changePosition() {
     var currentForm = $(this).find('.popover-form');

     var position = ( $(this).offset().top - currentForm.height() );
     if ( position <= 0 )   {
        currentForm.css('top', ($(this).offset().top + 10) );
        currentForm.css('right', '0');
     }else{
        currentForm.css('bottom', ($(this).offset().top - (position + 10)));
        currentForm.css('right', '0');
     }
  }

  $('.main-btn').on('mouseover', changePosition);
```

CSS . Remove top:87px from css

```
 .main-btn:hover .popover-form {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   background: #edeae4;
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   width: 285px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vevopecova/3/edit?html,css,js,output)

To check menu at bottom just remove all `<br>` tags from html.

Comment: I can't remove `top:87px` because it shows position relative to parent button (87px is the height of the button).

Comment: But anyway I tried this variant and it doesn't work: now form is always displayed on the top and never on the bottom

Comment: can't understand what you exactly want ?

Comment: I want this form dispayed on the top of the button when it doesn't go in the window. And nothing change when it completely visible in the window (display on the bottom)

Comment: [This is when form doesn't go in window](http://savepic.ru/7138621.png) ----

[And this in the regular case, everything is ok, the bottom of the page is far](http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=93ba86e14c86854709987540b1e54c31)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/vevopecova/1/edit?html,css,js,output   . check this demo.. add <br> tags to check  window top pf link if space available in widnow

Comment: I've learnt that `offset().top` is position from the top of the **document**, not the **viewport** that I needed - that was diffilculty. I wrote `$(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()` and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Im not quite sure if this is what you wanted to achieve,
but here's the JS:

```
function changePosition() {

    var currentForm = $(this).find('.popover-form');
    if ( ($(this).offset().top + currentForm.height() ) > $(window).height() ) {
      currentForm.css('top', '-87px');
    }
  }

  $('.main-btn').on('mouseover', changePosition);
```

and a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sapLty32/

Edit: I believe **Nishit's** way might be more what you're looking for. The negative positioning is a bit dirty.

```
function changePosition() {

    var currentForm = $(this).find('.popover-form');

    if ( ( $(this).offset().top + currentForm.height() ) > $(window).height() ) {
      currentForm.css('bottom', $(this).offset().top );
      currentForm.css('right', '0');
    }

}

  $('.main-btn').on('mouseover', changePosition);
```

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/4uj69gbt/